# My POST request goes to 302 Found and calls GET

Tags: php, laravel, .htaccess, permissions, apache2

I want to set up **AWS**, **Apache2**, **PHP7**, `Laravel 5.3`

When I try to `POST` to `/login`, it redirects me to `GET` `/login`.

`POST` `/login` is enabled in routes, it is in a list... but it doesn't work.

Can you help me to find an idea where to see a bug? Please.

Form:

```
    <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="POST" action="http://site.amazonaws.com/login">
<input type="hidden" name="_token" value="46ByPLZp03qEQqmdy6cq77DVe1xK837vcPRcrU4z">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="email" class="col-md-4 control-label">E-Mail Address</label>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <input id="email" type="email" class="form-control" name="email" value="powlowski.moriah@example.com" required="" autofocus="">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="password" class="col-md-4 control-label">Password</label>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <input id="password" type="password" class="form-control" name="password" required="">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-4">
            <div class="checkbox">
                <label><input type="checkbox" name="remember"> Remember Me</label>
             </div>
        </div>
    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-4">
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                                Login
                            </button>  
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
```

`.htaccess` file in public dir:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

**Apache2 conf** file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/lara-art/public
    <Directory /var/www/lara-art/public>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

**LoginController.php:**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class LoginController extends Controller
{
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Login Controller
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| This controller handles authenticating users for the application and
| redirecting them to your home screen. The controller uses a trait
| to conveniently provide its functionality to your applications.
|
*/

use AuthenticatesUsers;

/**
 * Where to redirect users after login.
 *
 * @var string
 */
protected $redirectTo = '/artworks';

/**
 * Create a new controller instance.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('guest', ['except' => 'logout']);
}

protected function credentials(Request $request)
{
    $field = filter_var($request->input($this->username()), FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) ? 'email' : 'username';
    $request->merge([$field => $request->input($this->username())]);
    return $request->only($field, 'password');
}
protected function attemptLogin(Request $request)
{
    return $this->guard()->attempt(
        $this->credentials($request), $request->has('remember')
    ) &&
    \Auth::user()->type->name!='art_lover';
}
protected function sendFailedLoginResponse(Request $request)
{
    \Auth::logout();
    return redirect()->back()
        ->withInput($request->only($this->username(), 'remember'))
        ->withErrors([
            $this->username() => \Lang::get('auth.failed'),
        ]);
}

public function username()
{
    return 'login';
}
}
```

Comment: Is it redirecting you from `/login` to `/login/`, or vice versa?

Comment: can you show your login controller ?

Comment: updated with LoginController

Answer (score 1):

**Laravel** use `Auth::routes();`

with `GET` request **laravel** returns view,
but `POST` request **laravel** checks your login data correct or not...
if your login and passwords are not correct, it will be `redirect` back with errors.
And you can get laravel validation errors in view;

example:

```
@if($errors->any())
    
      @foreach($errors->all() as $error)
        <p>{{ $error }}</p><br/>
      @endforeach
   
@endif
```

or you may use this method in login controller

```
public function login(Request $request)
{

    $this->validate($request, [
        'email' => 'required',
        'password'   => 'required|min:6',
    ]);

    
   if(Auth::attempt(['email' => $request->email, 'password' => $request->password])){

            return redirect(base_url('/'));
    }

    return redirect()->back()->withInput()->withErrors(['email'=> 'error message']);
}
```

Comment: you can use `Auth::routes();` only one time in routes

Comment: I've commented. At the begining there were two Auth::routes(); Now - once. But it is there.

Comment: this is php server language you only check yourself in view

Comment: `@if($errors->any())
        
          @foreach($errors->all() as $error)
            <p>{{ $error }}</p><br/>
          @endforeach
       
    @endif`   please insert this code to your view blade and check it return error or not

Comment: `@if ($errors->has('email'))` ... and for password are in blade template

Comment: I've tried different logins/passwords, errors aren't on screen because POST goes to 302 and then it's authomatically download GET /login with empty fields... (oh... but email is completed as in previous time)

Comment: 302 not error response. It's redirect code. your request response redirecting back

Comment: ok now let check this code in your login controller `public function login(Request $request)
{dd($request->all());}`

Comment: `array:3 [▼
  "_token" => "46ByPLZp03qEQqmdy6cq77DVe1xK837vcPRcrU4z"
  "email" => "m.basra@live.com"
  "password" => "secret"
]`

Comment: your login controller working well now please check this code `public function login(Request $request) {dd(Auth::attempt(['email' => $request->email, 'password' => $request->password]));}`

Comment: this mean your login or password not correct and lareavel redirecting back to login again

Comment: when I type correct login/pass it goes to `ErrorException in GenericUser.php line 46:
Undefined index: id`

Comment: you can use custom error `public function login(Request $request)
{

    $this->validate($request, [
        'email' => 'required',
        'password'   => 'required|min:6',
    ]);


   if(Auth::attempt(['email' => $request->email, 'password' => $request->password])){

            return 'you are logged in';
    }else{

    return redirect()->back()->withInput()->withErrors(['email'=> 'error message']);}
}`

Comment: did you change id to uuid in User table?

Comment: it was in migrations as `uuid` (`id` is commented, `uuid` added before me), but model User has a hidden `id` field.

Comment: I hope. Thank you much! Now I know where to find! ))) Thank you!